# SOAP Envelope error

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, soapui

Hi I am a newbie to jQuery , I was just testing a sample SOAP request with the following code , but I am getting error ,Is this because of the server side or the code I have written is wrong? , I mean the syntax .Can anybody help me to check it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {

                alert("get ready");


                var soapMessage ='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                '<soapenv:Header>'+
                '<a:Action xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">'+
                'http://xxx/xxxx/xxxx/accountSummary'+
                '</a:Action>'+
                '</soapenv:Header>'+
                '<soapenv:Body xmlns:ws="http://xx.xx.xxx.com/">'+
                   '<ws:accountSummary/>'+
                    '</soapenv:Body>'+
                '</soapenv:Envelope>'; 

            var url = "http://127.0.0.1/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx?wsdl";
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                crossDomain:true,
                dataType: "xml",
                processData: false,
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",

                success: function (soapResponse) {
                    alert("success: " + soapResponse);

                },
                error: function (soapResponse) {
                    alert("Soap" + soapMessage);
                    alert("Failed: " + soapResponse);
                }

            });

            });    
            }); 
                    </script>
```

Comment: You have a soap call with the namespace prefix `a`, but the namespace is not declared in the soap call.

Comment: @MarkVeenstra : just edited ...check it please

Comment: Now the `<ws:accountSummary>` is not closed change it too `<ws:accountSummary />`

Comment: @MarkVeenstra  : Yeah done but stil getting the error ..Is the code syntax correct namespaces and tags ? Did I miss anything?

Comment: You are also missing <Action> namespace. Try with: <a:Action xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">...</a:Action>

Comment: @albciff : Yeah thanks I have edited the question ..still getting error.

Comment: Now your request looks ok to me. Can you share the error?

Comment: @albciff : this part works for me... error: function (soapResponse) {
                    alert("Soap" + soapMessage);
                    alert("Failed: " + soapResponse);
                }

Comment: I mean the error message not the error function definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54525/discussion-between-wolverine-and-albciff).